# Access controls of a frame passed by reference in a sub

Tags: excel, vba, frame, userform

I am trying to pass many MSForms.Frames of a UserForm to a sub that is supposed to do stuff with the textboxes they contain:

```
initFrame(frame1)
```

However, once passed, I cannot access the .Controls property of that frame anymore (added a watch during debug, all that's left are Items).

I have tried many different sub declarations, but they either don't compile or lose the properties...

```
Private Sub initFrame(ByRef currFrame As MSForms.Frame)
Private Sub initFrame(ByRef currFrame As MSForms.Object)
Private Sub initFrame(ByRef currFrame As Frame)
Private Sub initFrame(ByRef currFrame As Object)
```

In all case, I get a runtime error when it gets to

```
For Each ctl In currFrame.Controls
```

Do I have to do something special to access the controls ? Like casting ?

Here is the whole code (ignore the .Name assignements):

```
Private Sub initTabs()
initFrame (frPrDetails)
initFrame (frPcDetails)
initFrame (frScDetails)

End Sub

Private Sub initFrame(ByRef currFrame As Frame)
Dim ctl As Control
With currFrame
    For Each ctl In .Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
            If ctl.TabIndex <> 57 Then
                Select Case (ctl.TabIndex) Mod 7
                    Case 1
                        'ctl.Name = "tb" & ctl.tag & "MP"
                    Case 2
                        'ctl.Name = "tb" & ctl.tag & "HW"
                    Case 3
                        'ctl.Name = "tb" & ctl.tag & "SW"
                    Case 4
                        'ctl.Name = "tb" & ctl.tag & "IC"
                    Case 5
                        'ctl.Name = "tb" & ctl.tag & "ES"
                    Case 6
                        'ctl.Name = "tb" & ctl.tag & "CONT"
                    Case 0
                        'ctl.Name = "tb" & ctl.tag & "ST"
                End Select
            Else
                'ctl.Name = "tbPrTotal"
            End If
            ctl.Text = ctl.Name
        End If
    Next ctl
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple but very subtle.

First of all, by default, parameters are passed by reference, so :

```
Private Sub initFrame(currFrame As MSForms.Frame) ' ByRef is optional
```

But, if the parameter is an expression, then a new object/variable is created.
So believe it or not, `(frame1)` and `frame1` are not the same thing.

Back to the issue, when you call the function, either use:

```
Call initFrame(frPrDetails) ' note the lack of space before the opening bracket
```

or simply

```
initFrame frPrDetails
```

but not `initFrame (frScDetails)` which is equivalent to `Call initFrame((frPrDetails))`