# Loop through checkboxes to see which ones are checked

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that contains 10x check boxes.

Each of these check boxes should have a value. Say check box 1 should contain value "Medicine", check box 2 should contain value "Water".

I am giving the users the option to check any of these and press submit. On pressing submit, I would like to check which check boxes were ticked and combine the values.

I.e. if user ticks only check box 1 and 2, then the output will be "MedicineWater".

Rather than doing 10 nested IF statements and then doing all the possible permutations, which would take very long. I wonder if it is possible to loop through the check boxes and see which one is ticked (marked as True) and then store the value that should be assigned to it.

My simplified code is:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim i as Long
Dim Val1 as String
Dim Val2 as String
Dim Array()
Dim Final as String

Val1 = "Medicine"
Val2 = "Water"

For i = 1 to 2
   If Me.CheckBox & i  = True Then
      Array = Val & i
      Final = Join(Array, "")
   End If
Next i

Msgbox (Final)
End Sub
```

Can someone please advise me how to do this properly?

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to access them through`Me.Controls` - example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25423755/2877364  (I suspect there's a better dupe but am not finding it at the moment)

Comment: Another candidate, but not check boxes - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40816151/2877364

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following will do what you expect:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim Final As String
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
'loop through controls in your UserForm
 If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then 'if control is a CheckBox then
    If ctrl.Value = True Then 'if the checkbox is checked
        Final = Final & ctrl.Caption 'add the caption to the variable
    End If
 End If
Next ctrl

MsgBox (Final)
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

If what you need is to assign the caption of the given checkbox to a variable, you can do so like below, using an Array to store values for each checkbox, this example will only store values for checkboxes that are checked:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim Final() As String
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim counter As Integer

counter = 0
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
'loop through controls in your UserForm
counter = counter + 1
ReDim Preserve Final(counter)
 If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then 'if control is a CheckBox then
    If ctrl.Value = True Then 'if the checkbox is checked
        Final(counter) = ctrl.Caption 'add the caption to the variable
    End If
 End If
Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I assign the Caption to the ctrl @ FInal & ctrl.Caption? In other words, how to ensure that me.CheckBox7 is assigned to string Val7?

Comment: To elaborate my comment - caption is what I show the users. But to each checkbox - I have to assign another value (SQL string) to that checkbox. This is why I was assigning Me.CheckBox1 = Val1...

Comment: @OdaySalim I've updated my answer to let you add the values to an array, hope that helps.. :)